# KeyDown Event not registered for Up Arrow on any Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, windows-11

My Up arrow no longer functions properly. In a keyboard event viewer website, it looks something like this:

[image]

To add to the mystery, a keyboard tester website appears to show the up key working:

[image]

The key works in Windows Safe Mode which suggests some installed app is preventing the propagation of this key. However, I have no idea which app could be doing this, short of uninstalling everything.

How can I get my up key back?

Answer (score 1):

As booting in Safe Mode fixed the problem, this indicates
that some third-party application is responsible for it.

To locate the problematic application, you may use the free tool
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

This utility shows all programs configured to run during
system bootup or login in its "Everything" tab.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return
them later with another click.
You may avoid listing Microsoft products by
using the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*,
*Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*

I would suggest turning off startup entries in bunches,
drilling down to the startup program that causes this behavior.
Once identified, it might have some setting that can avoid the
problem, or can be left out of startup and only be invoked
when required (verify that once invoked it does not add
another startup entry, but such can again be disabled by Autoruns).

Start with applications that might have some keyboard
functionality or mapping, for example Microsoft's Power Toys.